# join a lookup table with a data table

Tags: join, table, netezza

I have the following schema in my database

Neighbors: ( central_id, neighbor_id)
Data: (central_id, value)

This schema is for a convolution algorithm which for each `central_id` I have 6 neighbors(it is hexagonal grid)
for example here is a part of my Neighbors table

```
Central_id|Neighbor_id
0|1
0|2
0|3
0|4
0|5
0|6
```

and here is my `data`

```
central_id|value
0|20
1|1
2|6
3|1
4|6
5|1
6|0
```

I want to join these tables in a way that I can sum `value` for each central_id
my final result is sth like this

```
central_id|sum
0|(1+6+1+6+1+0=15)
```

Here is some of my tries

this query gives me the central_id|neighbor_id|value

```
select nb.c ,ac.c,ac.value
from 
 neighbors as nb 
inner join data as ac on nb.neighbour_id=ac.central_id
```

but it's result is wrong, since value is `20` which is value of central_id.
this is my second try

```
select c as nb,value from data where c in(
      select nb.c 
from 
 neighbors  as nb 
inner join data  as ac on  nb.neighbour_id=ac.central_id
where  and ac.c=0
)
```

this query result is correct. It returns `neighbour_id` and it's value, but I can not sum them based on `central_id`
If I could end up with such result my problems would be solved

```
central_id|neighbour_id|value(of each neighbour_id not central_id)
0|1|1
0|2|6
0|3|1
0|4|6
0|5|1
0|6|0
```

Can some one give me some hints about fixing this problem?thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to how you propose to join the first table where every central_id is 0 to your second table where there is only one record with central_id = 0?

Comment: @Vérace My main goal is to find neighbors based on central id

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.central_id, sum(b.value) 
FROM neighbors AS a
JOIN data AS b
  ON a.neighbor_id = b.central_id
GROUP BY a.central_id;
```